# Assertion failure with segues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I copied my project and renamed it - I've managed this before without too much incident.

This time I am getting the following error on any segue performed.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate segueWithDestinationViewController:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.29.5/UIStoryboardSegueTemplate.m:90
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not create a segue of class '(null)''
```

I've cleaned the project, removed all DerivedData. All segues are correctly named and show on the storyboard. It seems to have nothing to do with main UI threads etc. The segue code worked fine before the conversion.

I'm thinking the solution might be to remove and re-establish every segue but would like to check before I start investigating that.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to open storyboard as 'source code' and search for old project name.

Comment: Bingo - thanks kirander - found some embedded segues in there - all sorted. How do I mark this as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to open the storyboard as 'source code' and search for old project name.

Answer (score 6):

- Find this segue in Storyboard,
- In Attributes Inspector select your new module (or check **Inherit Module From Target**)
  [image]

Answer (score 4):

This fixed it for me..

If you have just renamed your project, check in your Storyboard... Each of your Segues are probably still using the old Module. Click the little drop down and select the new Module...

You can view the module by clicking on the segue and looking at the info in the right panel, just like you would with a button, label etc.